# LEDs connected to GPIO pins flashing instead of constantly on

Tags: verilog, calculator, fpga, gpio, led

I've actually asked a previous question on this code, but that was before it was "working". Here is the Code:

```
module MatrixInput(CLOCK_50,MOutput, MInput, LEDR);
//10 -> 16 Cols INPUTS
//24 -> 18 rows OUTPUTS
input [16:10] MInput;
output reg [24:18] MOutput;
output [7:0] LEDR;
integer counter = 0;
input CLOCK_50; //50Mhz
reg [3:0] ButtonFlag;

initial counter = 0;


assign LEDR[7] = ~MInput[10]; //Assign Cols to Leds 7 to 4
assign LEDR[6] = ~MInput[12];
assign LEDR[5] = ~MInput[14];
assign LEDR[4] = ~MInput[16];
assign LEDR[3] = ButtonFlag[3]; //assign LED Rows to button Flag indicator
assign LEDR[2] = ButtonFlag[2];
assign LEDR[1] = ButtonFlag[1];
assign LEDR[0] = ButtonFlag[0];


always@(posedge CLOCK_50) begin

    if (counter > 3) //if counter is larger than amount of cases. reset to 0
        counter = 0;

    case(counter) //go through and set every row except one high which we will compare against columns
        0: MOutput[24:18] = 7'b1x0x1x1; //dont care about GPIO  23, 21 or 19 
        1:  MOutput[24:18] = 7'b1x1x0x1;
        2:  MOutput[24:18] = 7'b1x1x1x0;
        3:  MOutput[24:18] = 7'b0x1x1x1;
        default: counter = 0; //ideally shouldn't be needing a default case
    endcase


    if (MInput[10] == 1 && MInput[12] == 1 && MInput[14] == 1 && MInput[16] == 1)   begin
        ButtonFlag[counter] = 0;
    end else
        ButtonFlag[counter] = 1;

    counter = counter + 1;

end
endmodule
```

Right now LEDS 7 to 4 aren't on at "full" brightness when the relevant Column button is pressed indicating that it is actually flashing on and off extremely fast. MOutput and Minput are assigned to the GPIO pins.

My question is how do I fix this and get them to be constantly on when a button in their column is pressed.

Comment: This looks like it could be a nice question but just looking at your current code and description doesn't give away the relationship between the GPIOs you are using. I'd recommend you edit your question to explain how the `MInput`s are driven by the `MOutput`s dependent on any button presses. As an aside, reorganising  your code (maybe moving the button-related code into a sub-module) for more meaningful signal/port names might be beneficial.

Comment: Ok cheers, actually your comment has made me realise what the answer is to my own question haha.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was something along those lines. It just wasn't really clear from the code and description you gave. Glad my comment was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that it's because I'm cycling MOutput and Minput can only be on when MOutput is on the correct cycle, hence flashing of the column LED.